# Creating PyPi package - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement iso8601

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, pip, pypi

I'm creating a PyPi package with pip and trying to test that it works on the test environment (https://testpypi.python.org/pypi). Right now I have a package that appears to exist on the prod PyPi install but not on test. If I install the dependency with prod PyPi (ie. pip install iso8601==0.1.4) it works properly but if I install from the test PyPi (ie.  pip install iso8601==0.1.4 -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi) I get

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement iso8601==0.1.4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for iso8601==0.1.4
```

Which is the same error I get when I try to install my package:

```
pip install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi united-states-congress
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT2:
Nope. After deleting and recreating the virtualenv it looks like twine is now the problem.

```
$ mkvirtualenv congress
New python executable in /Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/bin/get_env_details
(congress) Bens-MacBook-Pro:congress bytenel$ pip install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi united-states-congress -vvv
Collecting united-states-congress
  1 location(s) to search for versions of united-states-congress:
  * https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/
  Getting page https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/
  Looking up "https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): testpypi.python.org
  "GET /pypi/united-states-congress/ HTTP/1.1" 200 23438
  Updating cache with response from "https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/"
  Analyzing links from page https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/
    Skipping link http://www.python.org (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/#left-hand-navigation (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/#content-body (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=browse (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=submit_form (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=rss (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=packages_rss (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/security (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=66150&atid=513504 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/ (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopDev (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/about (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/news (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/doc (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/download (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/community (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/psf (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/dev (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/0.0.5 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); unsupported archive format: .5
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=login_form (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=register_form (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=forgotten_password_form (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=openid (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=login&provider=Launchpad (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/google_login (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Found link https://testpypi.python.org/packages/c7/6e/93f72867917d20c83f85d712e9accb294b1afe374fa05b7157f15eea8626/united-states-congress-0.0.5.tar.gz (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/), version: 0.0.5
    Skipping link https://github.com/usgpo/bill-status (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/unitedstates/congress/wiki (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://sunlightfoundation.com/blog/2013/08/20/a-modern-approach-to-open-data/ (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/unitedstates/congress/wiki/bills (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/unitedstates/congress/wiki/amendments (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/unitedstates/congress/wiki/votes (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/unitedstates/congress/wiki/nominations (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/unitedstates/congress/wiki/committee-meetings (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/unitedstates/congress/wiki/bill-text (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://www.govtrack.us (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/unitedstates/congress/blob/master/test/test_bill_actions.py (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); unsupported archive format: .py
    Skipping link https://github.com/unitedstates/congress/issues (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://sunlightfoundation.com (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://www.govtrack.us/developers/api (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://sunlightlabs.github.io/congress/ (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/ (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); unsupported archive format: .0
    Skipping link https://travis-ci.org/unitedstates/congress.svg?branch=master%29%5d%28https://travis-ci.org/unitedstates/congress (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); unsupported archive format: .svg
    Found link https://testpypi.python.org/packages/c7/6e/93f72867917d20c83f85d712e9accb294b1afe374fa05b7157f15eea8626/united-states-congress-0.0.5.tar.gz#md5=f5f4cc57a30d40a9e0c34537f7f21141 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/), version: 0.0.5
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=show_md5&digest=f5f4cc57a30d40a9e0c34537f7f21141 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/unitedstates/congress (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=3 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=30 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=548 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=532 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=501 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/edumbill/doap/wiki (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=doap&name=united-states-congress&version=0.0.5 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/about/website (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://www.fastly.com/ (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://developer.rackspace.com/ (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link https://aws.amazon.com/s3/ (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.timparkin.co.uk/ (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
    Skipping link http://www.python.org/about/legal (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/united-states-congress/); not a file
  Using version 0.0.5 (newest of versions: 0.0.5)
  Using cached wheel link: file:///Users/bytenel/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/4b/bb/be/42835c677c099bf681c26b0bae8a80eaa971c5528284cf2f2b/united_states_congress-0.0.5-cp27-none-any.whl
Collecting twine==1.8.1 (from united-states-congress)
  1 location(s) to search for versions of twine:
  * https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/
  Getting page https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/
  Looking up "https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  "GET /pypi/twine/ HTTP/1.1" 200 22259
  Updating cache with response from "https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/"
  Analyzing links from page https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/#left-hand-navigation (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/#content-body (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/1.6.2 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); unsupported archive format: .2
    Found link https://testpypi.python.org/packages/aa/26/33253779822e82789fbc752cfe1027338718447fa724ae047cd2449ed8fd/twine-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/), version: 1.6.2
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link http://bugs.python.org/issue12226 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link http://webchat.freenode.net?channels=%23pypa (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/pypa/twine (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/code-of-conduct/ (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Found link https://testpypi.python.org/packages/aa/26/33253779822e82789fbc752cfe1027338718447fa724ae047cd2449ed8fd/twine-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=1be267ac5e8b34cd9a21dd3f4b8bf96a (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/), version: 1.6.2
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=show_md5&digest=1be267ac5e8b34cd9a21dd3f4b8bf96a (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/packages/aa/26/33253779822e82789fbc752cfe1027338718447fa724ae047cd2449ed8fd/twine-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.asc (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); unsupported archive format: .asc
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=56 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=104 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=147 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=150 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=160 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=162 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=170 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=214 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=527 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=531 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=533 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=538 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=566 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=587 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=605 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=553 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=554 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/requests (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/requests-toolbelt (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
    Skipping link https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?:action=doap&name=twine&version=1.6.2 (from https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/twine/); not a file
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement twine==1.8.1 (from united-states-congress) (from versions: 1.6.2)
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for twine==1.8.1 (from united-states-congress)
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/Users/bytenel/.virtualenvs/congress/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 514, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for twine==1.8.1 (from united-states-congress)
```

Comment: Seems like I might be able to specify the dependency location (from http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html) so I could potentially tell it to always look at the prod dep locale?

Comment: Nope doesn't work - not sure how to fix this. Seems stupid, the dependency is actually on the test PyPi site. https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601

Answer (score 8):

While this ticket is older, I ran into a very similar issue while testing my own packaged module on PyPi.

```
$ pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple tsl2591
```

When testing, I would push up the latest version after building using setuptools / setup.py, and then use pip to install the test version as seen above. I would get a similar missing package error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement smbus2 (from tsl2591) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for smbus2 (from tsl2591)
```

The problem was that the package I listed as a requirement, `smbus2`, was NOT LISTED on Test PyPi. It would only work if I pre-installed the library prior to running `pip install` again.

Hopefully this helps anyone who is running in Python packaging issues, because it racked my brain for days.

Comment: The solution listed here in a similar post helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57152360/1913726

Answer (score 0):

The correct index url is not https://testpypi.python.org/pypi but https://test.pypi.org/simple/

You should succeed with

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ united-states-congress
```

Comment: Still doesn't work with a separate error - "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement appnope (from united-states-congress) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for appnope (from united-states-congress)"

Comment: Why would the index be different?

Comment: @noname if that's a direct copy and paste, is "appnope" actually being required?