# How to test that PyPi install will work before pushing to PyPi? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-2.x, pypi

I have been having some issues figuring out how to get my Python package processed up to PyPi so I can install it easily with other dependencies for other projects (ie. with a requirements entry or a simple 'pip install xyz') - one such is listed here [Creating PyPi package - Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement iso8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083558/creating-pypi-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement). This led me down another rabbit hole which led to another question:

How can I test to make sure the my pip install command will work prior to pushing my package with a release to PyPi?

Answer (score 15):

If you just need to test whether `pip install` works from the built package, you can create it and then use `pip` to install it from local filesystem.

```
python setup.py sdist
pip install dist/mypackage-1.0.tar.gz
```

If you have been running `python setup.py install` already, ensure you run:

```
pip uninstall mypackage
```

to uninstall existing package first. You can encounter strange situations where mixing `python setup.py install` and `pip` locally, so run `pip uninstall` multiple times until says no more package to remove to be safe.

Comment: Nice, that's helpful. Thanks! It seems thought that using pip install installs directly from the prod resources, is there an equivalent for pip install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi <package> ? Mostly I'm just trying to detect and fix dependencies that don't exist in both places.

Comment: What do you mean by both places? I was going to mention testpypi, but wasn't sure whether it only uses that or falls back to real PyPi. Is that the issue you are talking about?

Comment: Yea, I think we're on the same page. Basically some packages I'm using don't fall back to the real PyPi when versioning is different on the test vs prod PyPi packaging which has made testing impossible for the staging area. I could just ignore it and use the prod env since this seems broken but that seems wrong.

Comment: In addition to when versioning is different, some packages just straight up don't exist in the test env but do on the real PyPi...which isn't frustrating at all...

Comment: Have you looked at using http://doc.devpi.net/latest/index.html at all?

Comment: I found it but haven't had time to look at it yet. Seemed a bit complex...wish pip would 'just work' but oh well.