# How to get PyPI to automatically install dependencies

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, pypi

How can I publish a package on PyPI such that all dependencies are automatically installed, rather than manually by the user.

I specify the dependencies in `setup.py` with `install_requires` as follows:

```py
setuptools.setup(name='myPackage',
    version='1.0',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Bio-Informatics'
                ],
    install_requires=['numpy', 'pandas', 'sklearn'],
    python_requires='>=3'
        )
```

And I have a `requirements.txt` file which is included in my `MANIFEST.in`:

```py
numpy==1.15.4
sklearn==0.20.1
pandas==0.23.4
```

However, after publishing on test.pypi when I try to install the package, I get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from myPackage==1.0.0) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sklearn (from myPackage==1.0.0)
```

This means that PyPI does not install the numpy dependency.
How do I enable automatic installation of my dependencies? 
Should I use a virtual environment when building and publishing the package? How do I do this?

P.S. I am entirely new to this so I will appreciate explicit code or links to simple tutorial pages. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried changing your `install_requires` line to `['numpy==1.15.4', ...]`? (that is, formatting it in the same format as your `requirements.txt` file)?

Comment: Changing 'numpy==1.15.4' in install_requires returns the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that `pip` is trying to get the dependency from `pypi` and not from `test`?

Comment: Thanks @norok2 . That's a possibility. But how do I specify where pip is to get the dependencies from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized that installing packages from test.PyPI does not install all packages, since some of these packages are hosted on PyPI and not test.PyPI.

When I published the package on PyPI as a pre-release version (1.0a1), instead on test.PyPI, the dependencies were correctly installed. Hence, the problem was purely with test.PyPI.

Answer (score 17):

You can specify multiple indexes via `--extra-index-url`. Point it to TestPyPI so your package is pulled from there, the deps from PyPI:

```
$ pip install myPackage --extra-index-url=https://test.pypi.org/simple/
```

However, the real root for the issue is that you have included the wrong dist name for the [`scikit-learn`](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/) package. Replace `sklearn` with `scikit-learn`:

```
setup(
    ...,
    install_requires=['numpy', 'pandas', 'scikit-learn'],
)
```

Comment: The frustrating part is that the link to the test.pypi.org page has a snippet to copy and paste that looks something like this: `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ mypackage==0.0.18`. I tried for over an hour to test an install without install dependency errors. The answer described above did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

This is an unfortunate (and known) downside to TestPyPI: The issue is that `sklearn` does not exist on TestPyPI, and by installing your package from there, you are telling `pip` to look for dependencies there as well.

Instead, you should publish to PyPI instead, and use a pre-release version so as not to pollute your versions. You can delete these pre-releases from the project later.

Comment: That's not the correct answer. `sklearn` is the wrong name for `scikit-learn` and exists on PyPI only to point the users to the right one. Publishing to PyPI won't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is my approach.

I like to use a requirements.txt file instead of putting dependencies in install_requires because it's easier during dev to run:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

To have pip install dependencies automatically, I include at the top of setup.py before setuptools.setup():

```
requirements = []
with open('requirements.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        requirements.append(line.strip())
```

Then in setuptools.setup():

```
install_requires = requirements
```

To install:

```
pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --upgrade --no-cache-dir --extra-index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/ <<package name>>
```

*--index-url* is telling pip to use the test version of pypi.

*--upgrade* forces an upgrade if a previous version is installed.

*--no-cache-dir* resolves issues with caching if doing a very quick re-release (pip doesn't pick up the new version)

*--extra-index* tells pip to look in the prod version of pypi if it can't find the required package in test (i.e. solves problems of dependencies not being available in test)

Answer (score 0):

Your `install_requires` should be of the form

```
...
install_requires=["numpy==1.15.4",
                  "sklearn==0.20.1",
                  "pandas==0.23.4"]
...
```

You can also use `>=` instead of `==` to allow for more recent versions of those libraries.

Comment: That doesn't work @varagrawal
Then I get the error:


`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.15.4 (from myPackage==1.0) (from versions:)
No matching distribution found for numpy==1.15.4 (from myPackage==1.0)`

Comment: Try changing the `==` to `>=`.

Comment: Still doesn't work @varagrawal. Error: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy>=1.15.4...`

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue at all. How should a version restriction help when the package is not found?

Comment: I wasn't aware that the particular package may not be available on the test index. This answer was based on my own experience publishing packages. Just trying to be helpful. :)

Comment: Voted this comment up because it's valid to declare fixed package versions & is helpful. It may not be helpful for the exact version the op is trying to install but that sounds like a lack of understanding of context from the op.